# What is the benefit of adding "routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes()" to RegisterRoutes()?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api-routing, attributerouting

According to the article "[What's New in ASP.NET MVC5](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=975)", you must add this to your RegisterRoutes() method in order to use Attribute Routing:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

...so that the method is now:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
}
```

I do not have that additional/middle call, and my attribute routing has been working just dandy.

So what does adding that do for me, if anything?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You only need this if you use attribute routing on your MVC controllers. Your WebAPI attribute routing works because of this line in WebApi.Config.cs

```
// Web API routes
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```